# Wrong display technology used in design. Cable comes off

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, display

This question is about the search term to use and technology names and not specific parts (since I don´t think that is allowed).

I used connector SFV24R-4STBE1HLF together with this display cable. See image.
It does fit but not properly (comes off easy). I think it has to do with red-marked areas on connector. Red arrow on display cable collides with that area.

I can buy another connector. But what parameter do I need to change for the connector?
In Digikey I see there is a parameter,"cable end type", for this part and it is stated as "tapered"

I saw another part (SFV24R-2STBE1HLF) that said "Straight, Tapered"

Is "straight" the correct one to use with this display cable type?
or is it some other search parameter that I need to look at?
(English is not my native language so I might be misunderstanding)

[image]

[image]

Comment: after inserting the cable you need to press the brown part of the socket into the black part of the socket

Comment: Yes, I know. That is not the issue. I believe that connector is made for cables with an opening for the red marked part in the cable. So belive I use the wrong type of cable for that connector

Comment: I've never seen a cable with a notch like that.

Comment: What connector does the display manufacturer recommend?

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple issues. One is the contour and the other is the thickness of the reinforced area of the cable.

You will usually find the information in the drawings of the connectors. In this case it looks like this:

[image: SFV24R-4STBE1HLF drawing]

(taken from [here](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/drawing/10116954.pdf))

So it looks quite a bit different and it suggests, that there should be a different contour on your cable.

How do you find a better replacement? Often the easiest way is to ask the display manufacturer or look in the datasheets (including the drawing, sometimes it's written there) of the display to find recommended connectors.

If you don't find anything suitable there, select for the right pitch and number of contacts, the correct contact position (top or bottom) depending on how you insert the cable. It looks like straight and tapered might be the right things to look for. But I'm not sure if that is always an available filter.

Then check the drawing and check it against your cable. It can be quite time consuming to do this. I'd say stick to reputable manufacturers first, where the information is easy to get to waste less time.

Looking at the [drawing](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/drawing/sfv12b_hlf.pdf) for the SFV24R-2STBE1HLF:
[image: SFV24R-2STBE1HLF drawing]

Which should also be able to handle cables with a taper to them.

Comment: Amazingly good answer to a question which at first sight looks "rather hard".